# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{} :java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

When I searched the error, I have found causes of the error. However, I cannot find the error in my code. Can you help me?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,IntroActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="net.nevzatgunay.pathytest.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

IntroActivity.java

```
public class IntroActivity extends AppIntro {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    addSlide(SampleSlide.newInstance(R.layout.slide_1));
    addSlide(SampleSlide.newInstance(R.layout.slide_2));
    addSlide(SampleSlide.newInstance(R.layout.slide_3));

    showSkipButton(false);
    setFadeAnimation();
}

@Override
public void onSkipPressed(Fragment currentFragment){
    super.onSkipPressed(currentFragment);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onDonePressed(Fragment currentFragment){
    super.onDonePressed(currentFragment);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onSlideChanged(@Nullable Fragment oldFragment, @Nullable Fragment newFragment){
    super.onSlideChanged(oldFragment,newFragment);
}
}
```

Also, I have three xml file like slide_1, slide_2, slide_3.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="This is Slide 1"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="54sp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.nevzatgunay.pathytest/net.nevzatgunay.pathytest.IntroActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                         at com.github.paolorotolo.appintro.AppIntroBase.addSlide(AppIntroBase.java:389)
                                                                         at net.nevzatgunay.pathytest.IntroActivity.onCreate(IntroActivity.java:16)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not called `super.onCreate()` from `onCreate()` of `IntroActivity`, before calling `addSlide()`. See [the library documentation](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro#basic-usage) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super.onCreate()` in the `onCreate()` function of your `IntroActivity`. It should be the first line of your `onCreate()` function, needed to intialise the Activity, otherwise the `@Override` annotations you make are pointless.